# Define EntityListeners in persistence.xml

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a **JPA mapping** of my model based on annotations.

My model is split from implementation / service classes into **two modules** :

- Model
- Impl (containing service implementions and Spring configuration)

The later depending of the first.

I would like to setup **listeners on some entities** of my model.
The problem is that I can only define those listeners in the **impl** module, because they rely on other services in this module.

Hence, I **cannot use annotation** for the entity listeners (since it relies on classes out of the scope of the Model module).

Can I define them (and only them) in a **persistence.xml** in the Impl module, together with the annotation based entities ? How ?

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? Im having the same and now stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to section 6.3. XML definition in the following document https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Comment: Please do not only post links, please add some more information (some kind of abstract) -- read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer section "Provide context for links"

Comment: The cited documentation does not answer the OPs question.